# How to add javascript code only in specific urls?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have a div element everywhere on the domain. and I want to delete it on ost page but not on the main page . for example I want to show it on `www.spiele33.de` but delete it on `http://www.spiele33.de/uncategorized/moto-x3m-4-winter/`
So, I want to do it with javascript

```
 <script>
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;

     if (currentUrl.indexOf('.de/') != currentUrl.length  - 4) // if it is not home page
     {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-title h2-simulate-h1");
 x.style.display= "none";

     }
    </script>
```

but it does not work

Comment: This should be done on serverside.

Comment: If you do need to do this in script (and I agree you probably don't), see if you can generate something on the homepage that you can test, e.g. put a specific class on the body tag and check for that rather than trying to test the URL.

Answer (score 2):

`location.pathname` contains everything after the domain, so check for `location.pathname === '/'`.

Comment: To be more specific if (location.pathname === '/') { // hide element } should do the trick